# Assign expression to a variable

Tags: unix, regex, bash-scripting

This code strips out any [].  It works great

```
echo "127[.]0[.]0[.]1" | tr -d "[]"
```

I would like to do the same thing but with shell scripting.  User would enter:

```
./test 127[.]0[.]0[.]1
```

Output should be: 127.0.0.1

I would like to assign it to a different variable.  I have something like this but I get a syntax error and I'm not sure why.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$1 | tr -d "[]"
echo $a
```

This works just fine:

```
echo $1 | tr -d "[]"
```

But I would like to assign it to a variable and I don't know how.

Answer (score -1):

```
a=$(echo "$1" | tr -d "[]")
```

That should work fine